# Wrong type of C# struct variable when converting from C++ union

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I'm working on accessing an external C++ DLL through C# code. The API specifies the following function

`BOOL WINAPI Foo(RESULT_TYPE *pOut);`

Where `RESULT_TYPE` is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
unsigned result;
unsigned length;
union {
// result message
BYTE message[4096 + 1];
// option selection
OPTION option[21];
} extra;
} RESULT_TYPE;

typedef struct {
BYTE available : 1;
BYTE label[20];
} OPTION;
```

I've imported the function via `DLLImport`:

```
[DllImport(..., CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern bool Foo(ref RESULT_TYPE pOut);
```

Where "my" `RESULT_TYPE` is defined this way:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct RESULT_TYPE
{
    public int result;
    public int length;
    public RESULT_Extra extra;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct RESULT_Extra
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4097)]
    public byte[] message;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 21)]
    public OPTION[] option;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct OPTION
{
    public byte available;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 20)]
    public byte[] label;
}
```

What happens at runtime that upon executing `Foo`, my `RESULT_TYPE.extra.message` variable contains an array of `OPTION`, rather than a byte array. Removing the `option` variable from `RESULT_Extra` makes this behavior disappear, but I do need `option`, of course...

I've tried experimenting and researching and the closest thing I can think of is the issue mentioned [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/GemingLeader/marshaling-unions/) - that I'm using both value- and reference-types in my overlapping RESULT_Extra and that

> managed code does not permit value types and reference types to overlap

Is there a way for me to create a struct that contains both types? Is there a way to avoid the union by creating a struct with a type that can be somehow casted to both the union types externally?

Comment: Ideally this ought to generate an exception.  When the pinvoke marshaller converts RESULT_Extra then it has an arbitrary choice to either create a byte[] or an OPTION[].  It has no way of knowing which one it should pick, it flips a coin.  You can probably make it land on the other side by swapping the fields, not a solution.  We don't know either, you'll have to explain how the caller of this method is supposed to know how to interpret the data.

Comment: According to the API you're supposed to use the value in the `result` variable in the `RESULT_TYPE` value retrieved - if you get some result codes you should use the `extra.message`, other codes require you to use `extra.option`. 
But shouldn't the pinvoke marshaller just initialize both fields with the same data but just in different types? Why would it initialize the `byte[]` as a `option[]` variable?

Comment: It shouldn't.   If you want the same kind of memory overlap that a native program gets with these arrays then you need to use the *fixed* keyword in C#.  Or just convert the byte[] to OPTION[] yourself, not particularly complicated here.  Do beware that the byte[] length of 4097 is iffy, technically the OPTION[] array can contain 255 elements so takes 1 + (3) + 255 * 21 =  5359 bytes.  If it does then right now you'll corrupt memory.